# Does Next Js help reduce bundle size?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, bundle, single-page-application, create-react-app

I am in the process of migrating a CRA React app to NextJs.
One of the the reason being it's already a mid size application. The bundle size is around 3MB. No I've not spent my time optimising the bundle.
The app is constantly growing in terms of the number of components getting added to it.
I wanted to know if NextJs would help reduce the bundle size of this ever-growing application. Does it dynamically send pages from server based on routes so that not everything has to be shipped on initial load?

Comment: Do you need server side rendering? Did you try with dynamic imports or lazy loading your components?

Comment: Sounds like you need code splitting. Next is mainly for server side rendering, in order to boost SEO first paint etc

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question I've not started optimising bundle size in my CRA. It is growing rapidly in terms of no. Of components/views. The application is not a public website having static content, rather it has Authentication and almost all the view sit behind authentication so I understand SEO is not important in such cases. I'm just worried about the bundle size which I need to understand if NextJs does something differently to tackle this than CRA.